# MultiBinding Converter Not Displaying Results

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, converters, multibinding

As part of learning to use binding in WPF correctly, I've created a small conversion program, converting things like temperatures, length, fractions to decimals, etc.  Everything has worked fine with the temperatures and fractions, as these are done with simple bindings and converters.  I'm running into a problem though with the length conversion, as it requires a MultiBinding in order to function.

For controls, I'm using two textboxes for the original length and converted length.  Each of these has a matching ComboBox where the user can select the unit of measurement (ie-cm, in, mm, etc).

Using breakpoints, I've established that the entries are getting to the Convert method, and that the code inside the method is calculating everything correctly.  The `result` variable even shows the correctly converted number at the end of the method call, but that number isn't making it back into the `lengthResult` TextBox.

I've tried every iteration I could think of to get this to work, and googled this for about 3 hours now.  I can't find the problem or a guide that shows a similar enough situation that I can make it work for this situation.  Can somebody please look this over and find the *(very likely)* simple mistake I'm making?

*Note: I have a `ConvertBack` function in the C# code, but there's nothing in it yet beyond the default `throw new NotImplementedException`, so I left it out.  I'll worry about that after the `Convert` works first. :)*

**XAML:**

```
<GroupBox Header="Length" DockPanel.Dock="Top">
        <GroupBox.Resources>
            <local:LengthConverter x:Key="lengthConverter" />
        </GroupBox.Resources>
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition />
                <ColumnDefinition />
                <ColumnDefinition />
                <ColumnDefinition />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition />
                <RowDefinition />
                <RowDefinition />
                <RowDefinition />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Label Content="Original Length:" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="10" />
            <Label Content="Destination Length:" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="10" />
            <ComboBox x:Name="originUnitSelect" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="0" ItemsSource="{Binding Units}" Height="{Binding ElementName=lengthEntry, Path=ActualHeight}" MinWidth="50" />
            <ComboBox x:Name="destinationUnitSelect" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding Units}" Height="{Binding ElementName=lengthResult, Path=ActualHeight}" MinWidth="50" />
            <TextBox x:Name="lengthEntry" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="10" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" MinWidth="250" />
            <TextBox x:Name="lengthResult" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="10" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" MinWidth="250">
                <TextBox.Text>
                    <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource lengthConverter}">
                        <Binding ElementName="lengthEntry" Path="Text" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged" />
                        <Binding ElementName="originUnitSelect" Path="SelectedValue" />
                        <Binding ElementName="destinationUnitSelect" Path="SelectedValue" />
                    </MultiBinding>
                </TextBox.Text>
            </TextBox>
            <Button x:Name="convertLength" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" Content="Convert" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Click="convertLength_Click"  Margin="10"/>
        </Grid>
    </GroupBox>
```

**C#:**

```
public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        double result = 0.0;
        double cm_to_mm = 10;
        double cm_to_in = 0.3937;
        double cm_to_ft = 0.32808;
        double cm_to_yd = 0.010936;
        double mm_to_cm = 0.10;
        double mm_to_in = mm_to_cm * cm_to_in;
        double mm_to_ft = mm_to_cm * cm_to_ft;
        double mm_to_yd = mm_to_cm * cm_to_yd;
        double in_to_mm = 25.4;
        double in_to_cm = 2.54;
        double in_to_ft = 1 / 12;
        double in_to_yd = 1 / 36;
        double ft_to_yd = 36;
        double ft_to_in = 12;
        double ft_to_cm = ft_to_in * in_to_cm;
        double ft_to_mm = ft_to_in * in_to_mm;
        double yd_to_ft = 3;
        double yd_to_in = 36;
        double yd_to_cm = ft_to_in * in_to_cm;
        double yd_to_mm = ft_to_in * in_to_mm;


        if(values[1] != null && values[2] != null)
        {
            switch(values[1].ToString())
            {
                case "mm":
                    if (double.TryParse(values[0].ToString(), out result))
                    {
                        switch(values[2].ToString())
                        {
                            case "cm":
                                result = result * mm_to_cm;
                                break;
                            case "in":
                                result = result * mm_to_in;
                                break;
                            case "ft":
                                result = result * mm_to_ft;
                                break;
                            case "yd":
                                result = result * mm_to_yd;
                                break;
                        }
                        return result;
                    }
                    break;
                case "cm":
                    if(double.TryParse(values[0].ToString(), out result))
                    {
                        switch(values[2].ToString())
                        {
                            case "mm":
                                result = result * cm_to_mm;
                                break;
                            case "in":
                                result = result * cm_to_in;
                                break;
                            case "ft":
                                result = result * cm_to_ft;
                                break;
                            case "yd":
                                result = result * cm_to_yd;
                                break;
                        }
                        return result;
                    }
                    break;
                case "in":
                    if(double.TryParse(values[0].ToString(), out result))
                    {
                        switch(values[2].ToString())
                        {
                            case "mm":
                                result = result * in_to_mm;
                                break;
                            case "cm":
                                result = result * in_to_cm;
                                break;
                            case "ft":
                                result = result * in_to_ft;
                                break;
                            case "yd":
                                result = result * in_to_yd;
                                break;
                        }
                        return result;
                    }
                    break;
                case "ft":
                    if(double.TryParse(values[0].ToString(), out result))
                    {
                        switch(values[2].ToString())
                        {
                            case "mm":
                                result = result * ft_to_mm;
                                break;
                            case "cm":
                                result = result * ft_to_cm;
                                break;
                            case "in":
                                result = result * ft_to_in;
                                break;
                            case "yd":
                                result = result * ft_to_yd;
                                break;
                        }
                        return result;
                    }
                    break;
                case "yd":
                    if(double.TryParse(values[0].ToString(), out result))
                    {
                        switch(values[2].ToString())
                        {
                            case "mm":
                                result = result * yd_to_mm;
                                break;
                            case "cm":
                                result = result * yd_to_cm;
                                break;
                            case "in":
                                result = result * yd_to_in;
                                break;
                            case "ft":
                                result = result * yd_to_ft;
                                break;
                        }
                    }
                    break;
            }
        }
        return result;

        //throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
```

Comment: As a note, your code could be simplified a lot. Doing a two-step conversion, first from source units to the standard unit meter, then from meters to the target unit, would save you the overly complicated nested switch statement.

Comment: In a second step you should create a view model that stores values only in SI units. You would then bind a view model property to an input and output field with two separate converters that only perform a single source/target unit to SI unit conversion.

Comment: Thank you for these suggestions, I was thinking there had to be a simpler way to do this, with less code repetition, but I couldn't think of how to do it.  The only approach I thought of was a series of methods that would basically replace the series of double constants (yd_to_ft, in_to_cm, etc), but that realistically would have been even longer, just slightly more organized,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `textbox` needs a string, not a `double`.

```
return result.ToString();
```

Should do the trick.

Comment: I tried that before (and once more just now to double-check) and it still ends in an empty lengthResult TextBox.

Comment: Did you do it for **ALL** of your `return result` statements? You have a lot throughout your converter

Comment: Yup, that was the issue.  I only changed it on the final one because there was ultimately only supposed to be a single return statement.  I had started with multiples, then realized I could drop it down to one (to avoid this exact problem), and apparently skipped over them when I was reviewing the code later.  I knew it would be something incredibly simple like this, just couldn't find it.  :)  Thank you immensely!

Comment: No problem!  Often you just need a second pair of eyes to look everything over.

Comment: That's my standard creed, and why I knew it would be a simple solution. :)